# Identifying an excerpt by Beethoven (Ddim7ㅡAbm/EbㅡEbㅡAbm)

Tags: identify-this-song, beethoven

While working on an assignment based on secondary leading-tone chords, I found this excerpt that I am not quite familiar with:

> [image]

I see a secondary leading-tone seventh chord to the dominant, then a cadential six-four, repeated Ebs which represent the V, and then the tonic chord.  The key is Ab minor.

Can someone identify this piece?

Comment: I don't know whether you did the analysis, but for me it's missing an implied Eb chord on the last eighth of the first measure.

Comment: @PiedPiper - I did the analysis.

Comment: @PiedPiper - it is Ddim7ㅡAbm/EbㅡEbㅡAbm. (vii*7/Vㅡi6/4ㅡVㅡi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the third movement of Beethoven's Piano Sonata no.31 in A flat (op.110) - *III. Adagio ma non troppo.*